# How to create a dictionary with key and multiple values based on the data queried from database

Tags: python, dictionary

New to python and was wondering how to create a dictionary with key and multiple values so that I can pass it to HTML to display it on the UI. Below is the data format.

Questions from questions table -

```
 [{'question_id': 1, 'question_text': 'How many servers run at max capacity?', 'category_id':  1, 'is_long_survey': 0}, 
    {'question_id': 2, 'question_text': 'Is the database getting replicated?', 'category_id': 1, 'is_long_survey': 0}, 
    {'question_id': 3, 'question_text': 'Where is the infrastructure located?', 'category_id': 1, 'is_long_survey': 0}]"
```

Choices for these questions come from choice table with question_id as the foreign key.

```
[{'choice_id' : 1, 'choice_text': '2', 'question_id': 1},
 {'choice_id' : 2, 'choice_text': '4', 'question_id': 1}, 
 {'choice_id' : 3, 'choice_text': '6', 'question_id': 1},
 {'choice_id' : 4, 'choice_text': 'Yes', 'question_id': 2},
 {'choice_id' : 5, 'choice_text': 'No', 'question_id': 2},
 {'choice_id' : 6, 'choice_text': 'global', 'question_id': 3},
 {'choice_id' : 7, 'choice_text': 'local', 'question_id': 3}]
```

So each question has lets say 3 choices as shown below.

To display question text and their choices on the UI, how do I create a dictionary of question text as key and may be choices as multiple array values? Any other data structure I can use to format the data?

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Also, why not combine (join) the two queries into one and work from there? And what is the desired result at the end?

Comment: I tried with the join, but the result set has questions duplicated based on the choices. so thought it will be difficult to work form there.

Comment: Are you concerned about performance? If not, iterate over `questions` and set a new key "choices" using `fliter()` based on `choices`.  Hopefully that gets you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```py
qDicts = [ 
    {'question_id': 1, 'question_text': 'How many servers run at max capacity?', 'category_id':  1, 'is_long_survey': 0}, 
    {'question_id': 2, 'question_text': 'Is the database getting replicated?', 'category_id': 1, 'is_long_survey': 0}, 
    {'question_id': 3, 'question_text': 'Where is the infrastructure located?', 'category_id': 1, 'is_long_survey': 0}  
] ## [ FROM YOUR EXAMPLE ] 
chDicts = [
    {'choice_id' : 1, 'choice_text': '2', 'question_id': 1},
    {'choice_id' : 2, 'choice_text': '4', 'question_id': 1}, 
    {'choice_id' : 3, 'choice_text': '6', 'question_id': 1},
    {'choice_id' : 4, 'choice_text': 'Yes', 'question_id': 2},
    {'choice_id' : 5, 'choice_text': 'No', 'question_id': 2},
    {'choice_id' : 6, 'choice_text': 'global', 'question_id': 3},
    {'choice_id' : 7, 'choice_text': 'local', 'question_id': 3}
] ## [ FROM YOUR EXAMPLE ] 


qustionChoices = {q['question_text']: [
    c['choice_text'] for c in chDicts
    if c['question_id']==q['question_id']
] for q in qDicts} ## [ OUTPUT ]
```

This uses [dictionary comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) (to form the `qustionChoices` dictionary itself) as well as [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) (to build a list of choices for each question). The resulting output (`qustionChoices`) should look like:

> ```py
> {'How many servers run at max capacity?': ['2', '4', '6'],
>  'Is the database getting replicated?': ['Yes', 'No'],
>  'Where is the infrastructure located?': ['global', 'local']}
> ```

---

You can also nest the relevant choices into `qDicts` so that it looks something like

> ```py
> [{'question_id': 1,
>   'question_text': 'How many servers run at max capacity?',
>   'category_id': 1,
>   'is_long_survey': 0,
>   'choices': [
>    {'choice_id': 1, 'choice_text': '2', 'question_id': 1},
>    {'choice_id': 2, 'choice_text': '4', 'question_id': 1},
>    {'choice_id': 3, 'choice_text': '6', 'question_id': 1}] },
>  {'question_id': 2,
>   'question_text': 'Is the database getting replicated?',
>   'category_id': 1,
>   'is_long_survey': 0,
>   'choices': [
>    {'choice_id': 4, 'choice_text': 'Yes', 'question_id': 2},
>    {'choice_id': 5, 'choice_text': 'No', 'question_id': 2}] },
>  {'question_id': 3,
>   'question_text': 'Where is the infrastructure located?',
>   'category_id': 1,
>   'is_long_survey': 0,
>   'choices': [
>    {'choice_id': 6, 'choice_text': 'global', 'question_id': 3},
>    {'choice_id': 7, 'choice_text': 'local', 'question_id': 3}] }  ]
> ```

by looping through it (with indices generated by [`enumerate`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate)) as below.

```py
for qi, qd in enumerate(qDicts):
    qDicts[qi]['choices'] = [
        c for c in chDicts if c['question_id']==qd['question_id']]
```

or, if you'd prefer the nested dictionaries to be in a new variable (like `q_wCh` below),

```py
q_wCh = [{**q, 'choices':[
    c for c in chDicts if c['question_id']==q['question_id']
]} for q in qDicts]
```

[ `**q` is used to [unpack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) each dictionary `q` in `qDicts` ]